# '%let' equivalent in SAS for setting variables equal to numbers used in math?

Tags: sas

I'm having the following problem.

I'm trying to define variables with values that are used in formulas.

For example,

%let Deductible = 1000;

(later in the code)

...(1500 - &Deductible)...;

This doesn't seem to work? When I hard code the values in the rest of my code, it works perfectly. Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: What does `doesn't seem to work` mean?  Show the full code, and the error message or undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS macrovariable values are text. So you need to use %eval for calculations.

```
%let a= 1000;
%put 10000-&a;/*resolves it text value*/
output is 10000-1000
%let a= 1000;
%put %eval(10000-&a);/*resolves it text value*/
output is 9000
```

Comment: thanks Kiran! That helps a lot. I have some calculations nested in "do" and 
"if" statement. do i just place '%eval' immediately outside the formula using the variable?

Comment: yes. or %eval in front of your macro variable as 1000+%eval(&a). use %sysevalf if you have decimals